# Inline title with beamer block environment

Tags: beamer

I'd like to create a block environment that has the title bolded and in with a background color but also in line with the body text.

For my uses having a separate title section wastes too much space.

Is this possible?

Comment: Are you talking about beamer export through Org mode? If so, say so and tag the question with `org-export`. If not, what does the question have to do with Emacs? In an case, providing an input file and specifying what you do to produce the output you get and then pointing out what in that output you would like changed, would go a long way towards making your question more attractive to potential helpers..